# PDF Reader Cucumber Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, cucumber, pdf-reader

I've been asked to write some tests to confirm text is contained within a PDF file.  I've come across the PDF reader gem which is all good at rendering text from the file except the output isn't too good.  I have a piece of text for example, that should read `Date of first registration of the product` but PDF reader sees this as `Date offirstregistrationoftheproduct`.  Thus when I run my assertion, it fails due to the spacing of the text.

My code:

```
expected_text = 'Date of first registration of the product'

file = File.open(my_pdf, "rb")
  PDF::Reader.open(file) do |reader|
    reader.pages.each do |page|
       expect(page).to have_text expected_text
    end
```

The result is an RSpec expectation not met error.

Is there a way I can get this text properly formatted so that my assertion can read it?

Comment: You you provide a sample PDF containing the text in question?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to sensitivity, albeit test data, I wouldn't be allowed to upload a copy :-(

Comment: Can't you generate a PDF with just the text? I'm not sure how to help you without any actual input.

Answer (score 0):

The page object of Reader is not text. If you want to get text from a pdf, you may use `page.text`. Using a regex may solve your problem.

Try something like below.

```
expected_text = 'Date of first registration of the product'

file = File.open(my_pdf, "rb")
  PDF::Reader.open(file) do |reader|
    reader.pages.each do |page|
       expect(page.text.match(/#{expected_text}/)).to be true
    end
```